# Prevent apps from getting list of installed apps on phone

Tags: privacy

How I can prevent apps from knowing which apps I've installed?

Is there something in premissions in settings or hack or trick with root access apps?

Answer (score 1):

### I'm not making my own answer as correct answer (although it is in some ways) to see if we have other options.

---

I found this [XPrivacy](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacy) that based on [Xposed](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811) and it let take control of most API's to send fake data or deny apps requests.

There are 3 things here that might be valuable:

- `Xposed` need root access. (and rooting device will wipe all data)
- Installation (From rooting device to using `XPrivacy` app) is not easy and user should be advance.
- `Xposed` not available for Android Oreo yet. [Xposed Github Issue](https://github.com/rovo89/Xposed/issues/236)

Here is installed version on OnePlus 3t on android 7.1.1 (Oxygen OS 4.3) and result is success:

[image: Using xprivacy to return empty list of apps for get apps list API]